# Reduce unwanted motion blur while using GPUImage to capture

Tags: ios, swift, camera, gpuimage

I'm writing an app in swift, and using GPUImage to capture and manipulate the images. I'm looking for a way to decrease the exposure time to reduce motion blur.  If you too move quickly in the frame it looks very blurry. I have good lighting, so I'm not sure why the exposure isn't fast enough.

I'm currently doing this to setup GPUImage:

```
self.stillCamera = GPUImageStillCamera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480, cameraPosition: .Front)
self.stillCamera!.outputImageOrientation = .Portrait
```

I then setup the filters I want (a crop and optionally effects).
I then start the preview:

```
self.stillCamera?.startCameraCapture()
```

And to capture a frame:

```
self.finalFilter?.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
var capturedImage = self.finalFilter?.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing such long exposure times is that you're using a GPUImageStillCamera and its preview to capture frames. A GPUImageStillCamera uses a AVCaptureStillImageOutput under the hood, and enables the live preview feed from that. The photo preview feed runs at ~15 FPS or lower on the various devices, and doesn't provide as clear an image as a GPUImageVideoCamera will.

You either want to capture photos from the AVCaptureStillImageOutput by triggering an actual photo capture (via `-capturePhotoProcessedUpToFilter:` or the like) or use a GPUImageVideoCamera and capture individual frames like you do above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Simply switching to GPUImageVideoCamera didn't seem to make much of a difference.  Is there some parameter when i used the GPUImageVideoCamera that controls effective shutter speed?  I've been playing around with inputCamera.setExposureModeCustomWithDuration() a bit and was able to more or less get the result I wanted, but I'm not happy with having to worry about adjusting the ISO myself to make sure the exposure is ok.